# Laravel artisan cron task not working on ubuntu

Tags: php, laravel, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, cron

I have been pulling my hair out for the past 5 hours over what I thought would be a simple task, enabling the cron feature for Laravel. I am running Laravel 5.1 on an Amazon EC2 Ubuntu LAPP stack server.

I have added the cron task to the cron jobs list using the command

```
sudo crontab -e
```

Then I have added the command listed in the laravel documentation

```
* * * * * php /home/bitnami/htdocs/project/app/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

I have made sure that cron is running and I can see that the task is running if I run

```
sudo grep -i cron /var/log/syslog|tail -3
```

Which returns

```
Mar  4 15:36:01 ip-172-31-7-174 CRON[15120]: (root) CMD (php /home/bitnami/htdocs/project/app/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1)

Mar  4 15:37:01 ip-172-31-7-174 CRON[15123]: (root) CMD (php /home/bitnami/htdocs/project/app/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1)

Mar  4 15:38:01 ip-172-31-7-174 CRON[15125]: (root) CMD (php /home/bitnami/htdocs/project/app/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1)
```

I have tested that the path has not got any typos in it by running the command from the command line and it works properly

```
php /home/bitnami/htdocs/project/app/artisan schedule:run
```

Also I have added this cron task just to confirm that cron is actualy running

```
* * * * * echo "Cron" > /home/bitnami/htdocs/project/app/artisan/file.txt
```

I have also made sure the file is executable by doing the following but this has not fixed the issue either

```
chmod 755 artisan
chmod 777 artisan (I am aware this is dangerous)
chmod +x artisan (Suggested on fourms)
```

Does anyone have any suggestions where I'm going wrong here.

Comment: you are running your cron as root-user. did you test if your command executes successfully as root? sudo php /home/bitnami/htdocs/project/app/artisan schedule:run Also sending the output of that cron to a file instead of nirvana could help ;) * * * * * php /home/bitnami/htdocs/project/app/artisan schedule:run >> /my.log

Comment: When you run the command from command line are you running it as `sudo` cause your `sudo crontab -e` means the commands in there will be run by root.

Comment: Also what do you have scheduled to run in your laravel app?

Comment: @Pitchinnate Lots of DB inserts and I have also added a task which has \Log::info('Cron'); in it just to make sure its not a DB issue. Also I am aware about sudo crontab -e.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've experienced this and found a solution. It's because of unknown reason in bitnami, so that php command not recognized by cron. I used this command to make it working :

```
* * * * * /path/to/php/bin/php /home/bitnami/htdocs/project/app/artisan schedule:run 1>> /dev/null 2>&1
```

Comment: @Hariyanto Wijaya Please see my latest post. I'm not so sure this immediate solution works for me, maybe you can assist me.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41324164/cron-jobs-with-laravel-5-3-on-ubuntu-16-10-x64/41324235?noredirect=1#comment69852669_41324235