# Cron Jobs with Laravel 5.3 on Ubuntu 16.10 x64

Tags: php, linux, laravel, ubuntu, cron

I'm running a Digital Ocean's Ubuntu 16.10 x64 and have deployed the php Framework Laravel 5.3.28 on the server. 
For the most part everything is working as normal however I'm trying to get the crontab to call artisan commands like `php artisan schedule:run` so that laravel's task scheduler can be put to use.

I do not wish to download any extra packages to make this work as I feel there shouldn't really be a need to since the cron can call, what looks like, any command if properly coded.

**What I'm trying to do:**

From within the `crontab -e` I'm trying to properly write the Ubuntu correct way to call `php artisan schedule:run`

**What I've done:**

I've currently tried multiple different ways of writing this command and nothing is working as noted below:

```
#Attempt for cron
SHELL=/bin/bash
#PATH=????? <---Confused if this is even needed
* * * * * php /path/to/artisan scheduled:run 1>> file.log 2>&1
* * * * * /path/to/php artisan scheduled:run 1>> file.log 2>&1
* * * * * /path/to/php artisan scheduled:run >> file.log
* * * * * /path/to/php artisan scheduled:run 1>> file.log
* * * * * /path/to/php artisan schedule:run
* * * * * /path/to/php /path/to/artisan scheduled:run 1>> file.log
```

I've gone to multiple resources to try and find the answer but nothing seems to be the answer to my specific problem.

**Resources:**

- https://laracasts.com/series/intermediate-laravel/episodes/2?autoplay=true
- http://laravel.io/forum/03-05-2014-automated-mysql-backups?page=1
- https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/setting-up-larvel-cron
- https://community.centminmod.com/threads/how-to-run-a-cron-job-properly.2287/
- https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/scheduling
- https://laracasts.com/lessons/recurring-tasks-the-laravel-way
- https://laracasts.com/index.php/discuss/channels/laravel/laravel-artisan-commands-trough-cron-tab
- https://deploybot.com/guides/deploy-a-laravel-app-to-digitalocean

**Conclusion:**

At this point I'm stuck beyond stuck. Can someone please help me? All I'm trying to do is call the php artisan command using Ubuntu's cron and I don't know the exact way to do it. ANY and all assistance is greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance,

Happy Holidays!!

Comment: My cron line is exactly like this: `* * * * * php /home/spacemudd/laravel/public/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1`

Comment: @Spylot If you put this as an answer I'll mark it correct. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here we go. That's how mine looks like. :)

`* * * * * php /home/spacemudd/laravel/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1`

Answer (score 1):

Several of your crontab entries should work. If they appear to not be working the next question is whether you have installed the `php-cli` package? Without it you will not be able to run php scripts from the command line, only via a web server. If you haven't already I would recommend installing php7.0-cli via:

`sudo apt-get update`

`sudo apt-get install php7.0-cli`

The case **could** be made that when you downloaded php7 via `sudo apt-get install php7.0-fpm` it downloaded a version that would work with Laravel 5.3 but not necessarily for cron jobs calling php commands with Ubuntu. This is a hypothetical though and I feel might still be worth investigating.

Comment: I'll check this stuff out as soon as I can. If this provides me direction to the solution I will mark this answered. Thank you very much!